# Java doesn't print string in the textview

Tags: java, android, textview

my problem is this:
I have 2 text view, in the first a text that changes from "your X is" to "you are"("you are" is stored in a string) and in the latter a number that could assume any value or, if another value is "0", just become "perfect"(this took from a string).
All this after a click on a button.
The problem is that the first text changes while the second change from 0 but if the first value ( that i said before ) is 0 ( or minus 0 ) just doesn't change... It not assume the value of the string i want.
I hope you got the problem, this is the code.

```
if (risultato <= 0) {
                    risultatoX.setText("0");
                    X.setText(R.string.youAre);
                    risultatoOre.setText(R.string.perfect);
                    risultatoOre.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#259b24"));
                    hr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    X.setText(R.string.First);
                    risultatoOre.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#757575"));
                    hr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

Comment: Is there an exception being encountered?

Comment: Try getResources().getString(R.string.name);

Comment: Are you using an adapter? Try calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to force an update of the view

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get String from resources you need use getResources().getString() method.

For example:

```
X.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.youAre));
risultatoOre.setText(getResources().getString(perfect));
```

Comment: This is true if you are in an `activity`.  If you are in a `fragment`, you will have to have a reference to the parent activity.

Comment: Then just use this code this.getParent().getResources().getString(R.string.youAre)

Comment: I solved, it was only a problem of the emulator, because on my mobile phone it is ok! :)